# Dependente DropDown duplo em Yii2

Tags: yii2

Como posso resolver esta implementação abaixo, para que a mesma execute as 2 rotinas de dependência associado ao mesmo evento onChange:

Exemplo:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_data_type', [
        'hintType' => ActiveField::HINT_SPECIAL,
        'hintSettings' => [
            'placement' => 'right',
            'iconBesideInput' => false,
            'onLabelClick' => true,
            'onLabelHover' => false,
            'onIconClick' => true,
            'onIconHover' => false,
            'title' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">'.Yii::t('app','Tipo de Dado')
        ]])->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(DataTypes::find()->asArray()->all(),'id_data_type','name'),
        ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Selecione opção'),
            'onchange'=>'$.get( "'. \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('dependent/getviewcomponentinput').'", { id: $(this).val() } ).done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model,'id_data_view_component_input').'" ).html( data ); } );',
            'onchange'=>'$.get( "'. \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('dependent/getviewcomponentoutput').'", { id: $(this).val() } ).done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model,'id_data_view_component_output').'" ).html( data ); } );',
        ]);
    ?>


<?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_data_view_component_input', [
        'hintType' => ActiveField::HINT_SPECIAL,
        'hintSettings' => [
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'placement' => 'right',
            'iconBesideInput' => false,
            'onLabelClick' => true,
            'onLabelHover' => false,
            'onIconClick' => true,
            'onIconHover' => false,
            'title' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">'.Yii::t('app','Componente Visual de Entrada')
        ]])->dropDownList([],['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Selecione Opção')]);
    ?>


    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_data_view_component_output', [
            'hintType' => ActiveField::HINT_SPECIAL,
            'hintSettings' => [
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'placement' => 'right',
                'iconBesideInput' => false,
                'onLabelClick' => true,
                'onLabelHover' => false,
                'onIconClick' => true,
                'onIconHover' => false,
                'title' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">'.Yii::t('app','Componente Visual de Saída')
            ]])->dropDownList([],['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Selecione Opção')]);
    ?>

class DependentController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionGetviewcomponentinput($id)
    {
        switch ($id) {
            case 1: // Boolean

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['input_representation'=>true,'boolean_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;

            case 2: // Integer

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['input_representation'=>true,'integer_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;
            case 3: // String

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['input_representation'=>true,'string_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;
            case 4: // Float

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['input_representation'=>true,'float_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;
        }

        if (!empty($types)) {
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                echo "<option value='" . $type->id_data_view_component . "'>" . $type->name . "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }
    }

    public function actionGetviewcomponentoutput($id)
    {
        switch ($id) {
            case 1: // Boolean

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['output_representation'=>true,'boolean_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;

            case 2: // Integer

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['output_representation'=>true,'integer_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;
            case 3: // String

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['output_representation'=>true,'string_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;
            case 4: // Float

                $types = ComponentDataView::find()
                    ->where(['output_representation'=>true,'float_representation' => true])
                    ->all();
                break;

        }

        if (!empty($types)) {
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                echo "<option value='" . $type->id_data_view_component . "'>" . $type->name . "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }
    }

}
```

O que preciso: Ao selecionar o DropDownList do campo ***id_data_type***, deverá ser atualizado (Dependente DropDown) os campos ***id_data_view_component_input*** e ***id_data_view_component_output***, através das rotinas ***actionGetviewcomponentinput*** e ***actionGetviewcomponentoutput*** utilizando o evento ***onchange***.

Comment: Qual o erro? O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Ele somente atualiza o dropdown do último evento associado ao id_data_type, correspondente ao id_data_view_component_output. Preciso que atualize os 2 dropdowns id_data_view_component_input e id_data_view_component_output.

Comment: Elabore melhor sua pergunta amigo, não está nem um pouco compreensivel. Seja mais objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer chamar as duas rotinas (input e output) no mesmo evento?

Se for este o caso, no seu exemplo você esta registrando dois eventos de "onChange", fazendo que o segundo sobrescreva o primeiro e seja o único chamado. O correto é enviar os dois gets e chamas as duas rotinas no mesmo evento (como no código abaixo).

Caso você precise chamar um evento após o outro, utilize os callbacks de "success" para a primeira rotina e o "done" para a segunda.

```
['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Selecione opção'),
'onchange' => '
    $.get("'.\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('dependent/getviewcomponentinput').'", { id: $(this).val() } ).done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model,'id_data_view_component_input').'").html(data);});
    $.get("'.\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('dependent/getviewcomponentoutput').'", { id: $(this).val() } ).done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model,'id_data_view_component_output').'").html(data);});
',
]);
```